# Graphical interpretation of $f(z)=\sqrt{9-z^2}$ at purely imaginary numbers.

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Consider the function $f(z)=\sqrt{9-z^2}$. When $z\in\mathbb{R}$, the graph of the function is:

[image]

When $z$ is purely imaginary, such as $z=5i$, how can we interpret the function graphically? I assume that it is possible to take such a domain of $f$ since $(9-z^2)\geq0$ when $z$ is purely imaginary.

Please let me know if my question or assumption is wrong.

Comment: Wolfram alpha does this for you http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(9-(it)%5E2)

Comment: In order you have a true problem on imaginary numbers you can not try just with $z^2$.

Comment: @Piquito I don't think all imaginary numbers can be the domain.

Comment: I mean your problem as it has been posted is almost evident, too easy.

Comment: @Piquito Yes, now I feel so too. But sometimes even easy things are complicated by the head. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Kappa.- You are right, what you say is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $z=it$ with $t \in \mathbb R$, then $f(it)=\sqrt{9+t^2}$.